# Flash hiding mouse right button click and closing control buttons

Tags: flash-cs3

how can i fix the stage size of a swf file while it run (there should not be right click on the screen, there should not be any minimize, maximize and close button

please help me

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no way to disable the right-click in Flash, unless you use JavaScript. One person has created a universal code that basically "disables right-clicking in Flash", allowing you to customize it. This is great for games and to enhance the interactivity between the user and your application. The details about this solution can be found [here](http://www.uza.lt/blog/2007/08/solved-right-click-in-as3/) (credit goes to Uza). There is a downside to this: this code only works for flash applications that are running on a web browser, such as Firefox and Internet Explorer.

It is not possible to change your stage height and width dynamically, unless you use full screen and/or scaling. To do that, use the following code:

```
import flash.system.fscommand;
    /***********************************
    *fullscreen flash system command   *
    * "true" sets you to full screen,  *
    *"false" sets you to windowed mode.*
    ***********************************/

    fscommand("fullscreen", "true");   //default to false;

    /***********************************************************************
    *allowscale flash system command                                       *
    * "true" scales your application depending on the size of the window,  *
    * fullscreen or not.                                                   *
    *                                                                      *
    *"false" does not scale your application, regardless of                *
    * the size of the window, full screen or not.                          *
    ***********************************************************************/

    fscommand("allowscale", "true");  //default to true;
```

Finally, as for disabling the maximize, minize and close buttons in the window, there are a number of classes and programs out there that can do this for you. I strongly suggest you test out [Zinc Builder](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/) and see if it gives you what you want. There is basically no way to do this kind of "disabling" in Flash alone: you need a third party class or program.

Good luck.